# Comparing the url segment to string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i have done this:

code behind:

```
var uri = new Uri(Request.Url.ToString());
if ("newsFeed" == Request.Url.Segments[2])
{
    L1.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
}
```

the url of a the page is:

```
http://localhost:52040/ClientSide/newsFeed/allEr.aspx
```

so it's suppose to work and enter the `if`, but it doesnt

what is the problem?

Comment: Why can't you use a debugger?

Comment: if you put a breakpoint at the `if` line, what is `Request.Url.Segments[2]` equal to?

Comment: i have added .contains("newsFeed") and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Well `Segment[2]` would be `newsFeed/` not `newsFeed`. So you can do:

```
if ("newsFeed" == Request.Url.Segments[2].Trim('/'))
```

Or use `string.TrimEnd`

An easier way to debug these problems in future is to use a debug point and watch window. There you can see the value of `Request.Url.Segments[2]`

See: [How to: Use Debugger Variable Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx)

By the way [`Request.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is already of type `Uri`, you don't have to create a new instance of `Uri` with `ToString`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 if(Request.Url.Segments[2].Contains("newsFeed"))
```

Comment: The same problem applies to previous answer. The segment is `newsFeed/` not `newsFeed` so it will never find it. An option though is to provide a custom comparer function to use in Contains.